# How to handle complex transformations in circe decode

Tags: scala, circe, refined

Let's say that I have JSON

```
{"some": "123"}
```

And I want to create a custom decoder that would decode it to

```
case class Test(some: Long Refined NonNegative = 0)
```

So first I would need to decode `JSON` to `String`. Then turn `String` to `Long` which may throw an error which I can wrap in `Try` and use `Decoder.decodeString.emapTry`. But then I have to turn `Long` to `Long Refined NonNegative` which can be done via method `refinedV[NonNegative](x: Long)` which returns `Either[String, Long Refined NonNegative]`. And on top of all that, there is the default value I have to handle. Its gets very messy.

How can I manage such complex transformations during decoding, are there more complex structures than `emap` and `emapTry`?